# Change File in WebContent during runtime

Tags: java, file, jsf

I would like to exchange the background image in my JSF application. To do this I want to replace the image file in the WebContent folder on my appliaciton. This there a way to do this during runtime or do I have to look for another solution?

Answer (score 0):

instead of changing files, can not you put all images in `webContent` and handle in code to which image wants to show?

I had a situation to display images based on users role, so kept role1 and role2 images and handled in code.

If images are coming at run time, keep all images at out side of `webapps` folder (Somewhere like config) and use the specific image. My suggestion is, don't keep dynamic data in side `webapps` folder, this will remove once your server restart.